# Flutter IAP's not initiating payment popup after being cancelled once

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am using the [official in-app-purchase library](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/example) to handle billing. I have essentially copied the exact [working example for my app](https://github.com/ItsCalebJones/SpaceLaunchNow-Flutter/blob/master/lib/views/settings/settings_page.dart). After clicking an In-App-Purchase the App Store pop ups as expected - if the user cancels that purchase for any reason and then goes back and clicks the IAP again, the App Store no longer attempts to pop-up. This is true after reboots, re-installs, new versions, etc. that product is no longer reacting to user input.

The one interesting thing to note - this behavior is not seen whatsoever when testing through TestFlight.

Answer (score 1):

Many flutter developers facing issue in IAP, check this thread:
[GitHub: Flutter IAP iOS issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43957)

You can try this alternative solution:

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase
- https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_inapp_purchase